# Register image file format for Android gallery

Tags: android, gallery, media

Is it possible to register a new media file format that can be viewed with Android's built-in image gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this cannot be done. The registering for file format is done in Gallery's AndroidManifest.xml. So you cant change it.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected. I might save my own image file format along with a .png image as a work around.